# Parametrizing relationship depth Neo4jphp

Tags: cypher, parameterized, neo4jphp, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. I have the following query in which I tried to parametrize the `depth` value for the relationship and  it shows an error, If I remove parametrizing the `depth` value it works perfectly.

```
 $query="MATCH (a:user{id:{usd}})-[:likes*1..{depth}]->(b:product{id:{pid}})
         return a";
 $result = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $query,
           array('usd' => 1234,'depth' => 3,'pid'=>3456));
```

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct and this is not a problem related to neo4jphp. Cypher does not allow you to parameterize the depth of a relationship. If your depth has to be dynamic, you'll have to build your query like this:

```
 $depth=some_value;
 $query="MATCH (a:user{id:{usd}})-[:likes*1.." . $depth . "]->(b:product{id:{pid}})
         return a"
```

I'm not a PHP developer, so the syntax might not be 100% correct. But I guess the main idea is clear.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation

Comment: Is there prepared statement in neo4j?

Comment: No, no such thing I'm afraid.